# How do I change the delay of CSS transitions?

Tags: html, css, reverse

I would like to make this current CSS code transition in reverse. When I hover with the cursor off, it will start "packing up" from the last cube.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.main>div {
  font-family: "Comfortaa";
  border: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.main:hover>#t {
  padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
}

.main:hover>#r {
  padding: 20px 20px 75px 20px;
}

.main:hover>#o {
  padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
}

.main:hover>#c {
  padding: 20px 20px 125px 20px;
}

.main:hover>#h {
  padding: 20px 20px 150px 20px;
}

.main:hover>#e {
  padding: 20px 20px 175px 20px;
}

.main:hover>#j {
  padding: 20px 20px 200px 20px;
}

#t {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  transition: padding 500ms;
}

#r {
  background-color: LightSalmon;
  transition: padding 500ms 0.5s;
}

#o {
  background-color: PapayaWhip;
  transition: padding 500ms 1s;
}

#c {
  background-color: PaleGreen;
  transition: padding 500ms 1.5s;
}

#h {
  background-color: LightCyan;
  transition: padding 500ms 2s;
}

#e {
  background-color: LightSkyBlue;
  transition: padding 500ms 2.5s;
}

#j {
  background-color: MediumPurple;
  transition: padding 500ms 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="t">T</div>
  <div id="r">R</div>
  <div id="o">O</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
  <div id="h">H</div>
  <div id="e">E</div>
  <div id="j">J</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the boxes to animate from left to right on hover, then from right to left when no longer hovered, correct?

Comment: How did you discover the delay property that currently exists in your code on each element? Or did you copy that code from somewhere else? Learning about the `transition-delay` property should inherently teach you that you can change the delay value so that items transition when you want them to.

Comment: @InSync yes, youre right

Comment: @TylerH In fact my teacher helped me with this, so she showed me also the transition-delay

Comment: @MariaGureshova Does that mean you already have a solution? If that's the case, I highly suggest that you post it as an answer to this very question so that future readers may benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rearrange the `animation-delay` values on your shorthand `transition` properties. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition.

```css
.main>div {
  font-family: "Comfortaa";
  border: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.main:hover>#t {
  padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
}

.main:hover>#r {
  padding: 20px 20px 75px 20px;
}

.main:hover>#o {
  padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
}

#t {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  transition: padding 500ms 1s;
}

#r {
  background-color: LightSalmon;
  transition: padding 500ms 0.5s;
}

#o {
  background-color: PapayaWhip;
  transition: padding 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="t">T</div>
  <div id="r">R</div>
  <div id="o">O</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse the `animation-delay` values (ie: the second time value of the `transition` property) between the regular state and the hover state :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.main>div {
  font-family: "Comfortaa";
  border: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.main:hover>#t {
  padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.main:hover>#r {
  padding: 20px 20px 75px 20px;
  transition: 500ms 0.5s;
}

.main:hover>#o {
  padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
  transition: 500ms 1s;
}

.main:hover>#c {
  padding: 20px 20px 125px 20px;
  transition: 500ms 1.5s;
}

.main:hover>#h {
  padding: 20px 20px 150px 20px;
  transition: 500ms 2s;
}

.main:hover>#e {
  padding: 20px 20px 175px 20px;
  transition: 500ms 2.5s;
}

.main:hover>#j {
  padding: 20px 20px 200px 20px;
  transition: 500ms 3s;
}

#t {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  transition: 500ms 3s;
}

#r {
  background-color: LightSalmon;
  transition: 500ms 2.5s;
}

#o {
  background-color: PapayaWhip;
  transition: 500ms 2s;
}

#c {
  background-color: PaleGreen;
  transition: 500ms 1.5s;
}

#h {
  background-color: LightCyan;
  transition: 500ms 1s;
}

#e {
  background-color: LightSkyBlue;
  transition: 500ms 0.5s;
}

#j {
  background-color: MediumPurple;
  transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="t">T</div>
  <div id="r">R</div>
  <div id="o">O</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
  <div id="h">H</div>
  <div id="e">E</div>
  <div id="j">J</div>
</div>
```